# Why is the keyboard (onKeyDown) event bubbling not accessible on the component, but is on the parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Search component which has an input field inside. All elements inside it receive the onKeyDown event bubbling. However, when I use the component, it doesn't listen to the event. It's parent, however does.

In the example below, when I press a key inside the search field, it prints 'parent', but it doesn't print 'component'

```
<div className="xyz" onKeyDown={(e)=>console.log('parent')}>
    <Search onKeyDown={(e)=>console.log('component')}/>
</div>
```

Is this expected behavior? Am I missing something?
Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/80974/
to test, open the console, select the input and click any keyboard key.

Notice the console.log in the component declaration never fires, but it's parent does.

Comment: `<Search>` is just a place holder for the rendered html, it doesn't actually exist in the DOM, so there is no element for that event to be attached. Use the developer's tools and look at the live elements, you will see there is no actual element `<Search>`

Comment: Sure, but if I want a component to listen to an event I'd HAVE to add a parent element to listen to the event? Shouldn't the component act as if it is an element? I thought treating components as if they were elements was part of the mindset!

Comment: From what I understand, Search exists in react's virtual DOM and the events you listen to using the notation above listens to synthetic events too, so they don't really need to be in the dom imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `<Search onKeyDown={(e)=>console.log('component')}/>` you don't set `onKeyDown` event listener on `Search` component. You are actually passing `onKeyDown` **property** to the component. So then you can write in your `Search` component:

```
return <div onKeyDown={this.props.onKeyDown}>
...
```

In DOM structure your `Search` component is a `<div>` element in which you wrap your `<input>`. So if you want to set listener on `Search` component, set it on `<div>`-wrapper inside of it.

Virtual DOM persists the structure of the original DOM and checks for its changes (it just watches a **view** part of the DOM). It doesn't care about event listeners.

Here is a modified version of the fiddle, that does what you wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/81069/